# Javascript Confirmation Message Condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to create a condition to show confirmation message to validate if a session is existing in the site before logging in.

If user is currently logged in the site with the same username / credential or if session is existing then it will call the confirmation message and execute the action after clicking OK.

How do I create the condition before calling the confirmation message?

```
function checkSession() 
{       
    //call SQL
    varSQL = "Select * from user_table where user = 'user'";

    objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
    objCmd.CommandText = varSQL;
    objCmd.CommandType = 1;
    objRec = objCmd.Execute();
    var user = objRec("user");

    if (if user is not null)
    {
        return confirm("Please click OK to terminate the session and proceed to login.");
    }
}

<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return checkSession()"/>
```

It doesn't work if I try to add another condition on the confirmation function which is checking from database

Comment: Does `function objRec()` work synchronously?

Comment: i tried putting it separately and it is being called when not inside the same function of the confirmation message

<%
varSQL = "Select * from user_table where user = 'user'";

    objCmd.ActiveConnection = objCon;
    objCmd.CommandText = varSQL;
    objCmd.CommandType = 1;
    objRec = objCmd.Execute();
%>

Comment: Write separately server-side and client-side.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: In your text, server-side code and client-side code were mixed. Then I can't tell you what is wrong with your JS.